# Objective C: Load storyboard from a pod/framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I'm trying to load a view controller that's in a .storyboard in a pod. I'm using the following which normally works:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard 
storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardName" bundle:nil];
NewViewController *newView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
```

What do I need to change it to so I can load from a pod?

Comment: Does the code in your question work?

Comment: @trungduc it works if the Storyboard is in the project. It doesn't work if it's in an external pod.

Comment: Hey there, did you find a solution for this question ? hope anyone can respond..

Comment: I have created a framework with storyboard and trying to access storyboard from my view controller with below code    NSBundle *bundleName = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"bundle id of framwork"];
        UIStoryboard *stainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"AssignTasks" bundle: bundleName];    but getting error "Exception: Could not find a storyboard named 'AssignTasks' in bundle NSBundle" .

Answer (score 6):

You should load it with it's bundle identifier

```
NSBundle* bun = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:"id"]

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard   storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardName" bundle:bun];
```

[image]

Comment: What would the 'id' be? The pod's name?

Comment: I already marked it as the answer but I'm having some issue. The storyboard is included as a resource_bundles. Any idea on how to load this? Hope it makes sense.

Comment: I get the error: Could not find a storyboard named 'StoryboardName' in bundle NSBundle "

Comment: This is actually a really good answer. Just look for the bundle identifier of your pod which is likely be "org.cocoapods.<podname>".