# Loading .storyboard from Cocoapod resource bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I have a cocoapod that has a couple of storyboards. I'm trying to load them into my project using the following:

```
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"org.cocoapods.FrameworkName"];

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard   storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardName" bundle:bundle];
```

But I get the error:

> Could not find a storyboard named 'StoryboardName' in bundle NSBundle

Even though it's in the resource folder:

[image]

What am I missing? How can I load a storyboard from the resource bundle?

Comment: A similar question was just asked earlier today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50354684/objective-c-load-storyboard-from-a-pod-framework